ROS2 rate blocked
I am having an issue with a ROS2 python script that I am not able to understand. I implemented a server for an action node. In the callback of the goal, I am calculating some data with a given time frame (just integrate a variable). this is the code
def execute_callback(self, goal_handle):
        
        # Fill the data
        print( "Received new goal" )
   
        curr_pos = goal_handle.request.initial_position
        goal_pos = goal_handle.request.goal_position
        vel = goal_handle.request.linear_velocity
        
        
        dist = math.fabs( curr_pos - goal_pos ) 

        rate = self.create_rate(50)
        step_t = 1.0/50.0
        
        feedback_msg = LinearControl.Feedback()        
        
        while dist > 1e-2:
            print("dist: ", dist)
            print("curr_pos: ", curr_pos)
           
            curr_pos = curr_pos + vel*step_t
            dist = math.fabs( curr_pos - goal_pos ) 
            feedback_msg.distance = dist
            goal_handle.publish_feedback( feedback_msg )
        
            rate.sleep() 
            
        print("Motion done")
        

However, the code is blocked after the rate.sleep, it is like if is never released. My question is, is it allowed to used the rate object into an action server? The rest of the code is pretty similar the classical way of creating an action server in python. It works in the case I change the rate with a classical time.sleep.

please add the code for create_rate

@ChristianFritz I assume that is the one provided in node.py. Unless OP is overwriting it, which could cause issues..

In this case, using Rate.sleep inside the action will cause a deadlock. This is because both the action callback and the sleep callback are being handled by the same mutually exclusive callback group. That is, the sleep call must wait for the action callback to complete before waking up. But of course this is impossible!
More explanation can be found in the Using Callback Groups documentation.
